# single bibliography master/slave tex files

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to use this template for my PhD thesis:[latex templates->dissertation template](https://www.tudelft.nl/en/tu-delft-corporate-design/downloads/)

This uses one master.tex called dissertation and slave.tex files to create chapters. It seems that citations only appear in the master file and not in the slave files. In the slave file it appears [?]. Is there a way to make dissertation.bib file also visible to the slave files.

This are the exact commands that I use in the master file to cite:

```
\references{dissertation}
\cite{Einstein1906}
```

I am using Texmaker+Miktex compilation sequence is: pdflatex+bitex+pdflatex(x2)+view pdf (BELOW IS MASTER.tex code)

```
\documentclass{dissertation}

\begin{document}

\include{title/title}

\tableofcontents

\include{summary/summary}
\include{preface/preface}
\include{chapter-1/chapter-1}
\include{conclusion/conclusion}
\include{epilogue/epilogue}
\include{acks/acks}
\include{cv/cv}
\include{publications/publications}
\references{dissertation}
\end{document}
```

And this is the slave.tex

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chapter_1}
\cite{Einstein1906}
\authors{Albert {\titleshape Einstein}}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\section{Document Structure}
\section{Title Page}
\section{Chapters}
\section{Fonts and Colors}
\references{dissertation}
```

So if I `\cite` a document in slave.tex I get [?] as an output in my pdf. The problem is that dissertation.bib and bbl file is not automatically generated inside chapter 1 folder. If I copy paste dissertation.bib and bbl inside chapter folder it works.

I asked many people that are experienced users but nobody could fix it. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: assuming your chapters are input with `\input` or `\include` the usual `\cite`  command should  just work as normal.  As you have given no indication of your markup it is hard to guess what is wrong with your document.

Comment: Welcome! Please post a minimal working example here - don't expect people to follow a link and trawl through what is likely to be a huge amount of code which most people will have inductive reasons to be extremely badly written to boot. Terrible Template Temptations are the source of many TeX Tangles and the best advice is to resist them.

Comment: I update my post hope now it is more clear

Comment: Slightly clearer, but nobody but you can reproduce the problem because you've not posted compilable code. However, you need to be using something like `chapterbib` if you want per-chapter bibliographies with BibTeX. Alternatively, use Biblatex/Biber instead.

Comment: I guess you can download the folder and try to compile. There is a link in my post. I guess a minimal working example needs all the files to compile. Thank you for the effort